# Unable to create Hive unique paritions

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, hive-partitions

I am unable to create unique partitions. when i am uploading data, it's creating all the dates as partition again and again, even the dates are same

```
create table product_order1(id int,user_id int,amount int,product string, city string, txn_date string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

OK
Time taken: 0.133 seconds

```
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'txn' INTO TABLE product_order1;
    Loading data to table oct19.product_order1
    Table oct19.product_order1 stats: [numFiles=1, totalSize=303]
OK
```

Time taken: 0.426 seconds

```
    hive> 
    > set hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
    hive> 
    > set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = true;

    hive> 
    > create table dyn_part(id int,user_id int,amount int,product string,city string) PARTITIONED BY(txn_date string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
OK
```

Time taken: 0.14 seconds

```
    hive >
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dyn_part PARTITION(txn_date) select id,user_id,amount,product,city,txn_date from product_order1;
```

Result which i have received :-

```
    Loading data to table oct19.dyn_part partition (txn_date=null)
     Time taken for load dynamic partitions : 944
    Loading partition {txn_date=04-02-2015}
    Loading partition {txn_date= 03-04-2015}
    Loading partition {txn_date=01-02-2015}
    Loading partition {txn_date=03-04-2015}
    Loading partition {txn_date= 01-01-2015}
    Loading partition {txn_date=01-01-2015}
    Loading partition {txn_date= 01-02-2015}
     Time taken for adding to write entity : 5
Partition oct19.dyn_part{txn_date= 01-01-2015} stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=1, totalSize=25, rawDataSize=24]
Partition oct19.dyn_part{txn_date= 01-02-2015} stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=1, totalSize=25, rawDataSize=24]
Partition oct19.dyn_part{txn_date= 03-04-2015} stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=2, totalSize=50, rawDataSize=48]
Partition oct19.dyn_part{txn_date=01-01-2015} stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=1, totalSize=26, rawDataSize=25]
Partition oct19.dyn_part{txn_date=01-02-2015} stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=1, totalSize=26, rawDataSize=25]
Partition oct19.dyn_part{txn_date=03-04-2015} stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=1, totalSize=26, rawDataSize=25]
Partition oct19.dyn_part{txn_date=04-02-2015} stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=1, totalSize=25, rawDataSize=24]
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 4.03 sec   HDFS Read: 4166 HDFS Write: 614 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 4 seconds 30 msec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that some dates contain spaces, some are without spaces:

`txn_date= 03-04-2015` and `txn_date=03-04-2015`

Try to add `trim`:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dyn_part PARTITION(txn_date) 
select id, user_id, amount, product, city, trim(txn_date) as txn_date 
from product_order1;
```

Also better use Hive compatible date format `yyyy-MM-dd`, it is sortable.

To format date and remove spaces at the same time you can use regexp_replace.
If your current format is `MM-dd-yyyy`, then you can format it like this:

```
select regexp_replace(' 03-04-2015','.*?(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{4})','$3-$1-$2') --fix accordingly if it is dd-MM-yyyy. In this case it should be '$3-$2-$1' in the replacement template.
```

Returns:

```
2015-03-04
```

Or load like this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dyn_part PARTITION(txn_date) 
select id, user_id, amount, product, city, 
       regexp_replace(txn_date,'.*?(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{4})','$3-$1-$2') as txn_date 
  from product_order1;
```

regexp means:

`'.*?` - any character zero or more times

`(\\d{2})` - first group of 2 digits which will be addressed in the replacement as `$1`

`-` dash literally

`(\\d{2})` - second group of 2 digits which will be addressed in the replacement as `$2`

`-` dash literally

`(\\d{4})` - third group of 4 digits which will be addressed in the replacement as `$3`

And as a replacement `'$3-$1-$2'` we take groups from regexp in proper order, delimited with dash. Supposed $3 is year, $1 is month, $2 is day in your dates. You place groups in proper order to get `yyyy-MM-dd` because it is not possible to understand which format are you using: `MM-dd-yyyy` or `dd-MM-yyyy`

Comment: Thank you. I have used trim, it worked perfectly. Can you please explain the regexp_replace function with the parameters which you told me to use.

Comment: @Priyanka explained. regexp_replace will convert date to the proper format yyyy-MM-dd. With your current date it is not possible to use predicates with > or <. like this: `where  txn_date <= some_date` date should be in the `yyyy-MM-dd` format

Comment: @Priyanka currently your dates are not sortable and comparable. For example 10-01-2018 is greater than 01-01-2019, this is wrong